# How to improve execution time of groupby aggregation to compute percentiles in spark?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I'm trying to set up a pyspark job that estimates p25, p50, p75, p90 on a daily incoming volume of ~700GB data. I'm running the job with 40 worker nodes each with 32G memory and 8 vCPU and yet ends up running for ~15 hours to complete. I'm assuming the delay is due to the fact where the value needs to be  sorted across nodes to compute percentiles. Is there an alternative that can speed up this process?

Schema of input data -

```
root
 |-- processed_date: date (nullable = true)
 |-- id: string (nullable = true)
 |-- experiment: string (nullable = true)
 |-- type: string (nullable = true)
 |-- value: double (nullable = true)
 |-- revision: string (nullable = true)
 |-- source: string (nullable = true)
 |-- region: string (nullable = true)
```

```
df_agg = df.groupby('processed_date', 'id', 'experiment', 'type').agg(
                             F.min('value').alias('min'),
                             F.max('value').alias('max'),
                             F.avg('value').alias('avg'),
                             F.expr('percentile(value, 0.25)').alias('p25'),
                             F.expr('percentile(value, 0.50)').alias('p50'),
                             F.expr('percentile(value, 0.75)').alias('p75'),
                             F.expr('percentile(value, 0.90)').alias('p90'))
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using only columns to repartition by means that it uses hash partitioner on the columns used in the expression using `spark.sql.shuffle.partitions`, so in the case that default shuffle partitions are not adequate this will not work well. (default is **`200`**)

u should set **`numPartitions as well as column expressions`**. for this case,
i would do something like this:

```
df=df.repartition(1000, *['processed_date', 'id', 'experiment', 'type'])
```

Or before applying repartition(using only columns), set the shuffle partitions:

```
spark.conf.set("spark.sql.shuffle.partitions",1000)

df=df.repartition(*['processed_date', 'id', 'experiment', 'type'])`
```

I would suggest you repartition and spill to disk before applying groupby in order to utilize **`adequate partitioning and in-memory computing`** (ensure single pass):

*using data spilled to disk will still be faster than not putting into memory at all.*

```
from pyspark.storagelevel import StorageLevel

df=df.repartition(1000, *['processed_date', 'id', 'experiment', 'type'])\
      .persist(StorageLevel.MEMORY_AND_DISK)
```

**NumPartitions** is computed by `workers * cores * (2 or 3)`(as almost all modern virtual cores are multi-threaded)  which gives 8 * 40 * 3 = 960, which I rounded to 1000

Comment: Thank you both, repartition worked like a charm and in-memory execution came down to 1 hour now. However, while using StorageLevel, I'm getting an error: `Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 800 in stage 2.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: ExecutorLostFailure (executor 17 exited caused by one of the running tasks) Reason: Container killed by YARN for exceeding memory limits. 22.6 GB of 22 GB physical memory used. Consider boosting spark.yarn.executor.memoryOverhead or disabling yarn.nodemanager.vmem-check-enabled because of YARN-4714.` This occur in laststep when writing results to s3.

Comment: the executor is getting killed because there is memory utilization overhead and there is not enough memory is left for yarn daemons ( happens sometimes with aggregations), try `spark.conf.set("spark.yarn.executor.memoryOverhead", 2048)`. with this u could also try to set `spark.conf.set("spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled", true)`

Answer (score 0):

You can try [repartitioning](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/_modules/pyspark/sql/dataframe.html) `DataFrame.repartition` the dataframe on the columns by

`df = df.repartition('processed_date', 'id', 'experiment', 'type')`

So that all the records related to a combination of the above columns will be in the same node.